# geração de um vetor através de operação algebrica

Tags: python

tenho um vetor "tensao" com cerca de 30 valores dentro, para gerar um novo vetor "defo_calculada2" preciso somar 0.2 em cada valor do vetor "tensao", acredito que tenha uma maneira correta de vazer esta soma no vetor

defo_calculada2=tensao+0.2

Answer (score 3):

A forma mais simples é utilizando *list comprehension* para gerar a nova lista:

```
tensao = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
defo_calculada2 = [t + 0.2 for t in tensao]

print(defo_calculada2)  # [1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2, 5.2]
```

Se for utilizar a biblioteca NumPy, basta adicionar ao *array*:

```
import numpy as np

tensao = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
defo_calculada2 = tensao + 0.2

print(defo_calculada2)  # [1.2 2.2 3.2 4.2 5.2]
```